# flex / bison : how can I switch two lexers on same input file

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

How can I handover an open file e.g. read by another scanner to the next scanner - and give it to the parser ?

Comment: Why? Just push a start state to switch to a different set of rules in the same scanner, and pop it when you want to get out of them.

Comment: Please, validate rici's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Flex buffers cannot easily be transferred from one scanner to another. Many details are private to the scanner and would need to be reverse-engineered, with the consequent loss of maintainability.

However, it is not difficult to combine two (or more) scanner definitions into a single scanner, provided that the semantic types are compatible. It is simply necessary to give them different start conditions. Since the start condition can be set even outside of a scanner action, it is trivial to switch from one scanner definition to the other.

Since Flex scanners are table-based, there is no real inefficiency in combining the two scanners; indeed, there may be some value in not duplicating the code. The combined table may be slightly larger than the sum of the individual tables, because there are likely to be more character equivalence classes, but on the other hand the larger table may allow better table compression. Neither of these effects is likely to be noticeable.

---

Here's a simple but possibly useful example. This parser reads a file and substitutes `${arithmetic expressions}` with the evaluated expression. (Since its just an example, only very basic expressions are allowed but it should be easy to extend.)

Since the lexical scanner needs to start in start condition `SC_ECHO`, it needs to be initialized. Personally, I'd prefer to start in `INITIAL` to avoid this initialization in this simple case, but sometimes scanners need to be able to handle various start conditions, so I left the code in. The error handling could be improved, but it's functional.

The parser uses a very simple `error` rule to resynchronize and keep track of substitution errors. The semantic value of the non-terminals `subst`, `file` and `start` is the error count for the file; the semantic value for `expr` is the value of the expression. In this simple case, they are both just integers so the default type for `yylval` works.

Unterminated substitutions are not handled gracefully; in particular, if EOF is read during the lexical scan for a substitution, no indication is inserted into the output. I leave fixing that as an exercise. :)

Here's the lexer:

```
%{
#include "xsub.tab.h"
%}
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
%option yylineno
%x SC_ECHO
%%
   /* In a reentrant lexer, this would go into the state object */
   static int braces;

   /* This start condition just echos until it finds ${... */
<SC_ECHO>{
  "${"        braces = 0; BEGIN(INITIAL);
  [^$\n]+     ECHO;
  "$"         ECHO;
  \n          ECHO;
}
 /* We need to figure out where the substitution ends, which is why we can't
  * just use a standard calculator. Here we deal with terminations.
  */
"{"           ++braces; return '{';
"}"           { if (braces) { --braces; return '}'; }
                else        { BEGIN(SC_ECHO); return FIN; }
              }

 /* The rest is just a normal calculator */
[0-9]+        yylval = strtol(yytext, NULL, 10); return NUMBER;
[[:blank:]]+  /* Ignore white space */
\n            /* Ignore newlines, too (but could also be an error) */
.             return yytext[0];

%%
void initialize_scanner(void) {
  BEGIN(SC_ECHO);
}
```

The parser exports a single interface:

```
int parseFile(FILE *in, *out);
```

which returns 0 if all went well, and otherwise the number of incorrect substitutions (modulo the issue mentioned above with unterminated substitutions). Here's the file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(const char* msg);
void initialize_scanner(void);

extern int yylineno;
extern FILE *yyin, *yyout;
%}
%token NUMBER FIN UNOP
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%nonassoc UNOP

%define parse.lac full
%define parse.error verbose
%%
start: file          { if ($1) YYABORT; else YYACCEPT; }
file :               { $$ = 0; }
     | file subst    { $$ = $1 + $2; }
subst: expr FIN      { fprintf(yyout, "%d", $1); $$ = 0; }
     | error FIN     { fputs("${ BAD SUBSTITUTION }", yyout); $$ = 1; }
expr : NUMBER
     | '-' expr %prec UNOP { $$ = -$2; }
     | '(' expr ')'  { $$ = $2; }
     | expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
     | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
     | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
     | expr '%' expr { $$ = $1 % $3; }
%%
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", yylineno, msg);
}

int parseFile(FILE* in, FILE* out) {
  initialize_scanner();
  yyin = in;
  yyout = out;
  return yyparse();
}
```

And a simple driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int parseFile(FILE* in, FILE* out);
int main() {
  return parseFile(stdin, stdout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! The question came up because I would like to "overread" something like a header - but currently this includes some keywords - that are recognized by the "second" scanner. How can I change the "context dependend" scanner rules ? without trying to define the "syntax" of the header that should be omitted. May be it is because of the regular expressions, wher I get trouble if I want to skip "anything" but later I need to assign Tokens to delimiters and identifiers...

Comment: needed more space : Of course, I can manually recognize the header - and then handover to the 2nd scanner and parser - this works - but I wanted to keep the "language" separated in the lex files - not hard coded.

Comment: ah - was not aware of scanner start conditions - and their purpose. Thought more on start symbol in production/parser. Will give it a try - when I better understand how to deal with them.

Comment: @sqller: Added an example, and flagged your non-answers as non-answers. On SO, an answer is not an extended form of comment; you should either edit your question (if you are providing more information about your original question) or ask a new question (if you have a different question).

Comment: Ok I think, I understood now. I can write a function that calls in my case `BEGIN (ignore)` or use another lex rule to set the start condition. But I must not initialize the start condition on the top of all definitions. Thanks to all who helped me understand the mechanism. ( Here I was also not aware that I could call `BEGIN `within the coding)

Comment: @rici Could you provide some examples to test all the branches of the lexer/grammar. I am trying to understand the lexer/grammar. With some examples, it will be great.

Comment: @rici For example, what is the correct input that would trigger `++braces`. I used multiple `{`, but I end up with errors.

Comment: @user1424739: the lexer and the parser are not tightly coupled. With that parser, no valid input can include nested braces. But if you added a syntax with braces to the expression grammar, the lexer would work unmodified. Really, it's just a rough outline of how to build an application. A complete all-features-included application would be far too big to put in an SO answer, and its complexity would hide the simple concept that this answer seeks to explain